# Check for Facebook permission approval in Unity3d before trying to login the user

Tags: ios, facebook, unity-game-engine, app-store, publish-actions

I am working on an Unity3d app an I need the user to be able to post screenshots to his wall. I am currently using Facebook sdk v6.0.

I am trying to get my "publish_actions" request approved. My problem lies in the iOS deployment. Facebook request either a simulator build or an app already uploaded to the App Store. Since the first option is not available since my app does not behave well in the simulator, I would like to implement the Facebook screenshot feature and upload the new release to the App Store.

My idea is to check wether the permissions has been granted or not before trying to log the user. With this method I would avoid ugly messages from Facebook and instead of that, I would show a message stating that "this feature will be available soon". As soon as the Facebook app has been approved and permissions granted, the app will automatically allow the users to log in.

Any ideas on how could I check if the publish_actions permission has been approved before trying to log in the user?

Thank you very much in advance.

Kind regards,

Aernarion

Comment: If I understand your question correctly, you want to check a user's Facebook permissions for your app without the user even being logged in to Facebook? If so, it can't be done. You can't have unauthorised access to user's information like that.

Comment: Hi, Goodsum. No, it isn't. What I want to know is if Facebook has already approved the permission request for my app before trying to login the user. I am talking about the app review process once you ask for publish_actions permission for your app.

Comment: AFAIK there is no way of determining that from within the app by using the API. // But the FB reviewers are quite flexible – for apps that simply can’t provide a way for them to actually test the feature, they are usually quite happy if you can provide a screencast/video that shows what exactly your app does, how the user triggers sharing and what the result on their timeline will look like in the end – so I’d suggest you try that approach instead.

Comment: Thank you, CBroe, but it seems that the app upload is now mandatory, since I tried to upload for review and it is asking to fill both fields. Any other ideas?

Comment: I finally couldn't achieve what I was trying. I just published the app at the Apple Store without having the permission granted. It wasn't an inconvenient to get the approval, but I ignore if it is not impediment or I was lucky and the reviewer didn't find it. After that, is was easy to get the permissions from Facebook.